# How do I (deep) copy an array in C?

Tags: c

Refering to http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13291, it says that I can use `memcpy` with the size to copy determined by `sizeof()`, however, isn't the array pointing to a pointer?

Other than iterating through the array, how can I use `memcpy` to deep copy an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Arrays are _not_ pointers, no matter what anyone tries to tell you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A multi-dimensional array is contiguously allocated. An array of pointers (of pointers...) is a different thing (and each sub-pointer should be allocated/copied/freed on its own).

Do not be confused by the fact that an unidimensional array and a single pointer can be used interchangeably in most situations, because they are not technically the same.

Answer (score 8):

In the linked example `int weekly_hours[5][5];`  allocates space for 25 integers. There is no further indirection, so you can safely use memcpy to duplicate it's values.

Answer (score 4):

To hopefully clear up some of the confusion:

- An array is a chunk of allocated, 
  adjacent memory cells.
- An array variable name can transform ("decay") into a pointer to the first element of the array, but not the other way around. This is done implicitly each time you use the array variable name in pointer arithmetics.
- You can use the sizeof() operator on the variable name of any statically alloced array, to get the number of *bytes* in the array. If sizeof() is used on a statically allocated, multi-dimensional array, the same applies.
- If you use the sizeof() operator on a
  pointer, you will get the size of a
  pointer (i.e. 4 bytes on a 32-bit
  machine).